Error in drf-social-oauth2 framework operation
According to the documentation created an Application with default settings. Then I configured python_social_auth, but when calling http://127.0.0.1:8000/auth/login/vk-oauth2/ I get an error ValueError at /auth/login/vk-oauth2/
not enough values to unpack (expected 2, got 1)
Exception Location: ..\.venv\Lib\site-packages\social_core\utils.py, line 58, in module_member
This is the function where everything stops:
def module_member(name):
    mod, member = name.rsplit(‘.’, 1)
    module = import_module(mod)
    return getattr(module, member)

How can I fix further work?

provide your settings.py so i can assist you debug properly
